# Monitoring variable access and object creation in Python

Tags: python

I'm toying with the idea, mostly theoretically, of implementing time travel in a game. The implementation I came up with is remarkably simple:

Everything that happens in a game world simulated by a Python program ultimately comes down to a single operation: a variable is altered.

Therefore, time travel can be implemented by recording every variable alteration; specifically, storing the value it had before it was altered and the time at which the alteration occurred. When time should be reversed, the program will iterate over the list of events until it gets to one whose timestamp comes before the destination time. It can also travel forward in time, assuming it has already traveled back, by performing the actions in the action list at the times they occurred originally.

Of course, the key part of this is a way to react whenever a variable is altered. I suppose it'd be possible to do this with descriptors, if I understand them correctly, but that'd be rather annoying. I'd prefer to have a way to make the time travel 'opt-out'; that is, the program records changes in any variable it isn't specifically told not to. Is there a way to do this in Python (without making yourself a custom interpreter, at any rate)?

Comment: "Everything that happens in any Python program" cannot be reduced to variable assignment. Even ignoring externally-visible side effects, things like the state of the call stack cannot be recorded in terms of assignment.

Comment: This idea reminds me of the Transaction or [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) pattern. The game state may only be modified by presenting it with a command object, whose attributes fully describes the proposed modification. This makes it easy to implement undo, redo, deferred execution, etc.

Comment: I highly recommend not trying to reverse the interpreter state. Reversing the interpreter state to implement time travel is about as necessary as smashing physical objects together is to implement a physics engine.

Comment: The idea of time travel as the basis of a game is full of potential, though. Check out [Achron](http://www.achrongame.com/site/); it has the best time travel system I've ever seen, though the rest of the game isn't as good.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not sure I understand; why do I care about the state of the call stack? Mind, I'm not talking about reversing time in the sense of the program itself, but reversing time in the world simulated by the program. I'll edit the question to clarify that.

Comment: If you're monitoring *all* variables you don't explicitly mark as untracked, that'll include loop counters, function arguments, functions themselves, whatever metadata tracks time travel, etc., unless you go around marking almost everything. That's so much of the interpreter state, I assumed you wanted to roll back the whole interpreter.

Comment: Also, reverting variables won't, say, update the screen to show the old state of the game, and how are you going to deal with things like `l += [a, b, c]`, where there's no unmodified list object to revert to?

Comment: @user2357112 I think I understand what you're saying. Yes, you would need to flag *every* object that doesn't correspond to an object in the game world as not-to-be-monitored. In the actual implementation of it I was thinking you could flag entire modules as non-monitored; the game it was supposed to be part of kept its UI and actual game simulation code in separate files. I don't see the problem with the example you provided; surely I could just store l before [a, b, c] is added to it? The time travel code doesn't need to update the screen, that's presumably going to happen anyway.

Comment: There *is* no original `l` left after the `+=`. Your model of how a program evolves and how the state of the program corresponds to the state of the game is missing too much. I highly recommend tracking the time-evolution of the game explicitly instead of trying to selectively rollback parts of the interpreter.

Comment: @user2357112 Well yes, obviously. But there was one before. I'm not rolling back parts of the interpreter; I don't care about the interpreter, the interpreter is just chewing data, and I'm altering it. I'm essentially saving the game every time a variable changes and then reloading those saves. I'm pretty sure there's some kind of fundamental miscommunication going on here, 'cos I don't get what the problem is. Perhaps we should take this to chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42618/discussion-between-user2357112-and-schilcote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, Python has some magic methods: http://www.rafekettler.com/magicmethods.html... One of which is `__setattr__(self, name, value)`:

> It allows you to define behavior for assignment to an attribute
>   regardless of whether or not that attribute exists, meaning you can
>   define custom rules for any changes in the values of attributes.

You could create a "time traveling" base class which overrides `__setattr__` in which you'd be able to record the time and value assigned to any attribute in one of the time traveling subclasses.

UPDATE -- Here's a concrete example in which `Gun` subclasses the `TimeTravelBase` class. `Gun`'s `color` attribute is opted out of its history, while new values assigned to `shots_fired` along with the times of assignment are appended to the `Gun`'s history:

```
import time

class TimeTravelBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.history = []
        self.blacklist = ['blacklist']

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        super(TimeTravelBase, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        if hasattr(self, 'blacklist') and name not in self.blacklist:
            self.history.append({'time': time.time(), 'name': name, 'value': value})

class Gun(TimeTravelBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Gun, self).__init__()
        self.blacklist.append('color')
        self.shots_fired = 0
        self.color = "black"

    def fire(self):
        self.shots_fired += 1

if __name__=='__main__':
    gun = Gun()
    gun.color = "red"
    gun.fire()
    from pprint import pprint
    pprint(gun.history)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'shots_fired', 'time': 1386281320.322638, 'value': 0},
 {'name': 'shots_fired', 'time': 1386281320.322645, 'value': 1}]
```

Comment: Ah, setattr would be an even simpler way to implement this. It's still opt-in, though, when I'd prefer this system to be opt-out. Is it possible to change Object.__setattr__?

Comment: @Schilcote: Yes, just implement your own `__setattr__`-method, do your logging or whatever needed and finally call `super(YourClass, self).__setattr__(self, name, value)` to execute the parent/super method for its business-logic.

Comment: Alas, it turns out the design as described doesn't take mutables into account; a game designed entirely without using them might work. Still, good answer, I'm surprised I didn't think of it myself. :P